# Initializing a variable with a function in a class

Tags: swift, class, initialization

I have a class sort of like the one below. It is simplified, but it illustrates my problem. I want to initialize the "number" variable with the function "square".

```
class SomeClass {
    let number: Int
    func square (num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }
    init(num: Int) {
        number = square(num)
    }
}
```

But when i make an instance of the class. For example

```
let instance = SomeClass(num: 2)
```

it throws the error: use of 'self' in method call 'square' before all stored properties are initialized.

How can i initialize the number by using the function?

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case you can use *class method*:

```
class SomeClass {
    let number: Int
    class func square (num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }
    init(num: Int) {
        number = SomeClass.square(num)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the only way, how to do what you want to do, is declare the number as var and initialize it with some value

```
class SomeClass {
    var number: Int = 0
    func square (num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }
    init(num: Int) {
        number = square(num)
    }
}

let instance = SomeClass(num: 2)
instance.number // 4
```